# What to do if ellipses are already in a text

Tags: punctuation, ellipses, quoting

What should I do to let a reader know that in a quote the ellipses aren't mine and have been placed by the original author? This is the quote:

> My home university did a study of its alumni a few years back, and they discovered that out of all the various degree subjects, the one that led to the highest average income was ... mathematics. (Stewart, Letters, 1)

Comment: @SvenYargs while those are somewhat helpful they don't quite get the context of what I'm saying.

Answer (score -1):

If you replace words with an ellipsis, the convention is to put it in square brackets:

> What should I do to let a reader know that in a quote the ellipses aren't mine [...]

That makes it clear that you added it yourself and that it wasn't in the original.

If that convention isn't explicit enough for your particular case, you could add a comment in square brackets to make it clear:

> Hodor Hodor Hodor ...
>
> [ellipsis in original]

Comment: *the convention is to put it in square brackets* Whose convention is this?

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
A good answer is comprehensive and contains an explanation of ***why*** it is correct.
Links to external resources are encouraged.
For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: @deadrat The Modern Language Association (MLA) style handbook (such as the 6th edition) used to require that ellipses not appearing in the original text be placed in square brackets. I believe (but am not positive) that they removed that requirement in more recent editions. Other stylebooks such as APA and Chicago never had that requirement.